# What does “conn” mean in mongostat utility?

Tags: mongodb

I'm troubleshooting an application issue that uses Mongo. I've just started to use the mongostat utility. Does the "conn" column show the number of established, authenticated TCP connections to the database, or does it show the number of database connections that are actually running an operation against the Mongo database?

Answer (score 1):

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/

The total number of open connections, meaning all authenticated connections.  They can be running,  runnable, waiting or in sleeping state.